# Dimensions that give maximum volum of a box

Tags: derivatives, quadratics, volume

So I have this formula : $4x^3 - 17.4x^2 +623.7x$
I have created this formula to find the volume of a box. Now I need to - calculate the dimensions of the box that gives the greatest volume. I have been trying for ages to do this with differentiation, but i continuously don't do it correctly.  Could someone please help me/ show me what to do?

Comment: I'm guessing $x$ is one of the dimensions of the box and you've plugged in numbers for the other two?  Because technically, in a volume, every term must have units of *length cubed*.  If that is the case, then I can help you

Comment: Stephen - you mean length cubed.

Comment: Haha yes sorry...

Comment: So take the derivative of your volume formula and set it equal to zero.  Unfortunately when you do that, you will find that your cubic equation has no maximum (in the real plane).  Your volume formula must have an error in it, becuase V gets larger (without bound) as x grows larger.

Comment: Is there a certain domain for $x$, given or implied in the original problem (which you should've described here, by the way)? Something like "$x\in[0,10]$"? If $x$ is one of the dimensions of the box, then we know that $x\ge0$. But we need to know more.

Answer (score 0):

There is no max to the function $4x^3-17.7x^2+623.7x$ as it is cubic, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8l-La9HEUIU) is a nice video explaining odd functions.

Hint: If you are trying to find critical points you'll want to first check to see if there exists any.

Double Hint: Try graphing the derivative :)